# Program stops running possibly because of garbage collection problems

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have the following format in a class called Extract. This class has a main method that is supposed to read lines from a text file and output them to another text file. This is the overview:

```
 Public class Extract{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      try{

        Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file_from)); // read from file
        Printwriter out = new PrintWriter ( new BufferedWriter (file_to))); // File to write to

        while(br.hasNextLine())
         {
            ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
            String some_sentence;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
              {
                 some_sentence = br.nextLine();
                 if (some_sentence != null){
                    sentence.add(some_sentence);
                  }
         }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < sentences.size() ; i++) 
         {
          some_sentence = sentences.get(i);
          // prepare sentence to be parsed
          Tree parsed = lp.parse(some_sentence);
          TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
          GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
          GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parsed);
          Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependencies();
          Iterator<TypedDependency> itr = tdl.iterator();

          out.println(some_sentence);
          out.println("\n");
          System.out.println(++count);
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
            TypedDependency temp = itr.next();
            out.println(temp);
            }
          }
      }

      } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Something failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}
```

Given that I am initializing the array `sentences` with 1000 new strings in each iteration of the while loop, could this cause my program to stop running? My program is exiting with the following error message:

```
NOT ENOUGH MEMORY TO PARSE SENTENCES OF LENGTH 500
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.createArrays(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:2203)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.considerCreatingArrays(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:2173)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:346)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.parseInternal(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:238)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.parse(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:530)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:301)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:279)
        at Pubmedparse2.main(Pubmedparse2.java:52
```

could it be that garbage collection is not working properly in the case where I release 1000 dead String objects in every iteration of the while loop? (As a note the packages listed in the error are a package used to parse sentences into grammatical relationships).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you getting an exception in the catch?

Comment: You would be getting - NoSuchElementException - if no line was found - in your first For Loop if lines are less 1000

Comment: @BobStout I apologize for not writing this, I am getting the following error: `NOT ENOUGH MEMORY TO PARSE SENTENCES OF LENGTH 500
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: I did not see the error it was in an errors log on the cluster I am using, I will edit my question.

Comment: As far as I know, Java will automatically GC when there are no more references to a variable or the variable is no longer in scope.  I agree with Aaron D below...there's something else going on.  Without seeing the rest of the code, however, I'm not sure what that something would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the garbage collector is a mysterious beast that pounces even experienced developers in unexpected ways, I doubt that it's involved in this case (unless your input file is bigger than 10 MB).

My guess is that you made a mistake in the code. Use the real debugger or [poor man's debugging](http://blog.foomatik.com/2012/08/24/why-poor-mans-debugging-is-not-so-poor/) to see what the code is really going.

**[EDIT]** It seems you're using [the Stanford NLP parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

From the documentation:

> at least 100MB to run as a PCFG parser on sentences up to 40 words in length; typically around 500MB of memory to be able to parse similarly long typical-of-newswire sentences using the factored model

Check the documentation of your Java VM to find out how to give it more memory.

Comment: @AaronDigula Hi, thanks for response. I did edit my question to add more details, could you check it again? Thank you sir.

Comment: @kolonel: The stack trace means the error happens in the part of the code which you didn't show us. What is `edu.stanford.nlp`? How much memory does it need? Where does result come from? Do you keep more than one result in memory?

Comment: After I prepare the sentence to be parsed, and after I parse it, I let go of the previous sentence that was parsed and then move on to the next sentence in the `sentences` ArrayList. I added the missing section about sentence parsing into the code, maybe you can look at it again, thanks for your help.

Comment: See my edits. The error message "NOT ENOUGH MEMORY TO PARSE SENTENCES OF LENGTH 500" is a bit ominous, though. Are you trying to parse sentences with 500 words?

Comment: Thank you, could you recommend a modification to my program where I could catch java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and then try to parse the sentence again. I am running this process along with other processes, so it may be that at that specific time there was not enough memory, so if I could have it try parsing again after it failed that might help me. Anyways many thanks!